# How to add a space to an object name in R

Tags: r

```
Piston_Rings<-diameter[1:25,]
```

I want my quality control graph NOT to have the underscore in the object name.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you need to provide more information. Show us your data and the code that you've tried which produces the undesired result. You might also want to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). For the record I did not downvote your question as I find the practice offensive, especially with those who are new to the site.

Answer (score 4):

At the moment there is an underscore (not a hyphen) in that object name. It is possible to construct objects whose names have spaces in them but in order to access them you will then always need to use backticks in order to get the interpreter to understand what you want:

```
> `Piston Rings` <- list(1,2)
> `Piston Rings`[[1]]
[1] 1
> `Piston Rings`[[2]]
[1] 2
```

The problem you incur is cluttering up your code, at least relative to obeying the usual conventions in R where a space is a token-ending marker to the parser. Hyphens (at least short-hyphens) are actually minus signs.

If on the other hand you only want to use a modified version of a name that contains an underscore as the title for a graph, then try something like this:

```
 Piston_Rings <- list()   # just for testing purposes so there will be an object.
 plot( 1:10,10:1, main = sub("_", " ", quote(Piston_Rings))  )
```

Answer (score 1):

@BondedDust's answer is correct, but (guessing, since you haven't been very specific) a simpler way to get what you want is just to specify `xlab` or `ylab` arguments to the `plot()` function.  Let's say you have variables `stuff` (x) and `Piston_Rings` (y).  If you just

```
plot(stuff,Piston_Rings)
```

then the plot will have "Piston_Rings" as the y-axis label.  But if you

```
plot(stuff,Piston_Rings,ylab="Piston Rings")
```

you'll get the label you want.  You can also include lots more information this way:

```
plot(stuff,Piston_Rings,
     xlab="Important stuff (really)",
     ylab="Piston Rings (number per segment)")
```

See `?plot.default` for many more options.